# How to claim a web driver element promise in JS console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm debugging my node.js web driver tests, and I'm inspecting elements in JS console.

I am using the `findElement` method, as documented here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html

However, this method returns a web element promise, as you can see here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js.src.html#l1857

I can't find any methods I can use in the console to claim this promise instantly, so that I inspect the web element:

[image]

What can I do with this promise to get the object so that I can inspect it in JS console?

Comment: What if you do: `driver.findElement(By.className('thumbnail')).then(function (elm) { console.log(elm); });`?

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't log anything. It just returns another promise and is never fulfilled. I even tried this: `driver.isElementPresent(By.className('thumbnail')).then(function (data) { console.log(data); });`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "claim". What do you expect to the result of your inspection?

Comment: Something like Java's `Future.get()`, where it blocks and returns the object that the promise is about, here a `WebElement` object.